# Laravel CORS variables

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I wanted to set up a dynamic CORS middleware which would check on the fly if the subdomain I am using is the valid subdomain for my server. I have tested the logic behind it and it works, but when providing a variable to the header, it seems as if something isn't right?

Here is the code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $originalDomain = config('session.domain');

    $parsedUrl = parse_url(request()->url());
    $splitDomain = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host'], 2);
    $subdomain = $splitDomain[0];
    $domain = $splitDomain[1];

    $subdomainValid = $parsedUrl['host'] != $originalDomain && $originalDomain == $domain;

    if(!$subdomainValid)
        return $next($request);

    $allowedUrl = $parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $subdomain . '.' . config('session.domain_without_dot');

    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $allowedUrl)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
}
```

I am getting the error that `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, but if I dump the variable I got, and paste it in, it works just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that got deleted. I'm new to this site and didn't have the proper formatting, plus I realized my solution isn't the answer to your problem. PS it wasn't an ajax request, it was a call to .ajaxSetup to send the CSRF token in the headers.

Comment: Have you considered https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors ? It permits wildcarded origins.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't suit my case as I have to crosscheck subdomain with whitelist from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by changing

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url(request()->url());
```

to

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
```

**Explanation**

Since this middleware is put on the server, when request goes through the middleware, the `request()->url()` is actually the value of the server URL, not of the subdomain requesting it. With this change I am fetching an URL of the subdomain which requested the server resource.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm parsing it and hitting against the original value in my config file. Do you reckon it can be abused?

Comment: No it's fine. I'm not thinking straight. CORS is to protect the user not your server so this is fine